# C++ Code doesn't output in Visual Studio Code when certain data structures are used

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, g++

I'm running into a weird bug in Visual Studio Code - I'm writing code in C++ using standard extensions (C/C++ extension pack) and if I write a simple program like this, it works fine:

```
int main() {
    #ifndef ONLINE_JUDGE
    freopen("input.txt", "r", stdin);
    freopen("output.txt", "w", stdout);
    #endif

    cout << "Hello World!" << endl;
}
```

However, the second  I declare a variable using STD include statements, such as a `map`, `vector`, etc., the code runs without errors but doesn't print anything.

```
int main() {
    #ifndef ONLINE_JUDGE
    freopen("input.txt", "r", stdin);
    freopen("output.txt", "w", stdout);
    #endif

    vector<int> test;
    cout << "Hello World!" << endl; // this no longer prints
}
```

Any ideas why this error is occurring? I have all the include statements I need as well:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>  
#include <complex>
#include <queue>
#include <set>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <list>
#include <chrono>
#include <random>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <stack>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;
```

Comment: There have been multiple questions like this in the past here. As far as I know all of them without resolution. Most likely you have something setup wrong in your environment. For example you might be linking to a different version of the C++ standard library than you are using the headers of. Without listing the exact steps you took to setup your development environment, there will not likely be a useful answer.

Comment: Is it something you are experiencing only in VS code? I don't think IDE has to do anything with this. Can you confirm if the code works from IDEs other that VS code?

Comment: You should remove most of these meaningless include directives and leave only those that are actually needed. In particular, never use <bits/stdc++.h>.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested your code, and it ran as expected.

Some ideas:

- When `ONLINE_JUDGE` is not defined, `freopen("output.txt", "w", stdout);` makes the output redirected to `output.txt`. Maybe you forgot checking the file instead of the console the second time you ran your program.
- Besides, since you were using Visual Studio Code, maybe you used an extension to run your program. The extension may not use your current working directory to run the program, which made the `output.txt` elsewhere. Also, check if `ONLINE_JUDGE` is set by the extension or your script.

BTW, if you use g++, `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` will include all headers of standard library, and there is no need for including other headers. But doing so will dramatically increase your compilation time.